# Activation PHP E-mail dosn't work

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I'd like to make new users activate their account by cliknig clicking link in emial email but aint ain't happening what's wrong with this code??

here is what i get after I open activation email link

```
ACTIVATION RESULTS

Your account could not be activated!

';} elseif ($doublecheck > 0) { echo "

Your account has been activated!

 Click Here to log in now.

  "; } ?>
```

her is my php code

```
 include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
// Get the member id from the URL variable
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $id); // filter everything but numbers for security
if (!$id) {
echo "Missing Data to Run";
exit(); 
 }
 // Update the database field named 'email_activated' to 1
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET emailactivated='1' WHERE id='$id'"); 
 // Check the database to see if all is right now 
  $sql_doublecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id' AND emailactivated='1'"); 
    $doublecheck = mysql_num_rows($sql_doublecheck); 
  if($doublecheck == 0){ 
  // Print message to the browser saying we could not activate them
 echo '<br /><br /><div align=\"center\"><h3><strong><font color=red>Your account could    not be activated!</font></strong><h3><br /></div>';} 
 elseif ($doublecheck > 0) {

echo "<br /><br /><h3><font color=\"#0066CC\"><strong>Your account has been activated!      <br /><br />
   </strong></font><a href='login.php'>Click Here</a> to log in now.</h3>"; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Did you verify that the `$id` variable is what you expect it to be?

Comment: @Jon Sturdevant I have no errors at all

Comment: Is your file starting with "<?" or "<?php"?

Comment: Sounds like your `$id` variable isn't what you expect it to be. Check its value.